# Masonry Not Working - Woocommerce & Genesis Grid

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, grid, masonry, genesis

This is the type of solution I'm hoping for...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using a form of image lazy loading.
Lazy loading does not always work with a masonry lay-out.
So, to solve the issue, disable lazy loading or switch from masonry to a grid style lay-out.

Comment: I think you use lazy loading unknowingly. Let's take a look at the HTML code of your page. `loading="lazy"` as an attribute connected to every image.